# PyApduTool exception while installing applet

Tags: javacard

I´m using PyApduTool to install an applet on my Java Card
but while downloading it, i get this exception:
    "Download Cap error: GP init update failed. recv: 69 82"

With an other card i get this one:
    "Download Cap error: Check Card Cryptogram failed."

I hope someone can help me

Comment: There is a great answer by Maarten Bodewes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23565199/3899583

Answer (score 0):

`69 82` stands for security issues. Try contacting your card provider for the keys.

What type of card do you have? Most Gemalto cards have default keys as `47454d5850524553534f53414d504c45`.

Try selecting card manager to see card's life cycle state.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @vlp

Please Conside that some cards may have the default keys as `404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f`

Comment: Maybe it is worth saying that the mentioned key for most Gemalto cards is diversified (direct use _probably_ won't work and _might_ cause harm) + please consider adding the "omnipresent" 4041..4E4F key to the answer as well.